# Missing Frameworks from Cocoapods after switching computers

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I recently switched computers and brought over my project but when I opened the workspace I noticed that all of my frameworks via Cocoapods were missing.

I closed the workspace and went into the folder directory and deleted the current xcworkspace, 'Pod' folder, and podfile.lock file, and ran a pod update and pod install. I also deleted the Derived Data for safety measures. However, after reopening the newly created workspace the frameworks were still missing and I am getting an error saying that functions that are within my frameworks have been renamed.

Can anyone point me to another solution? I feel like I've tried just about everything that I could find on here and what I know. Thanks in advance!

[Missing Frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0aVo.png)

[Framework Incorrect Full Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFaXe.png)

[Function Renamed Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8coUu.png)

Answer (score 0):

The frameworks are probably missing because they've not been built yet, but they will show up the first time you run the project.

The function rename warnings are probably because you're using a newer version of Xcode that is using Swift 4.2 by default. Usually the easiest way to tackle this is to upgrade your Pods to newer versions.

Comment: Thanks for answering. whenever I build the project some of the frameworks that are listed under 'products' are found but I still am missing the majority of them and thats when I receive the errors. I also tried a 'pod update' after running 'pod deintegrate' in the terminal, with no luck.

Comment: You need to fix the function rename errors before they'll show up. If the Pods aren't building, there's not a framework file for your app to use.